# COUNTIF not working with 'ends with value'

Tags: excel

As per below I cannot use a wildcard in an Excel query to do an 'ends with' count.  I believe everything is correct so any ideas welcome

| RANGE |
| --- |
| 18185513911 |
| 28185513911 |
| 28185513913 |
| 38185513914 |
| 48185513915 |

| VALUE |
| --- |
| 8185513911 |

`=COUNTIF('RANGE'!$A$2:$A$5,"1" & A1)` - works and shows a count of 1
`=COUNTIF('RANGE'!$A$2:$A$5,"*" & A1)` - fails and shows a count of 0 instead of the expected 2

Answer (score 1):

**In answer to the question**
Oddly enough, once you use wildcards in `COUNTIF`, it's looking for textual values.
So, what you're trying to do would work with numbers stored as text, but not numbers per se.

See [COUNTIF Help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34).
There you will see an explicit example where `"*"` is used to count any cells containing Text.
Indeed, if you test `=COUNTIF(RANGE!$A$2:$A$5,"*")` on your data you will see it only returns non-zero results for cells containing Text (including numbers stored as text), but not numbers as such.

**Other ways to approach this**:
a) You could use an array formula based on `SUM`:

```
{=SUM(IF(RIGHT($A$2:$A$5,LEN(A1))=TEXT(A1,0),1))}
```

b) You could  use array formula based in `COUNT`:

```
{=COUNT(IF(RIGHT($A$2:$A$5,LEN(A1))=TEXT(A1,0),$A$2:$A$5))}
```

c) You could use `SUMPRODUCT` as suggested by @basic:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(RIGHT($A$2:$A$5,LEN(A1))=A1&""))
```

d) Etc... (I'm sure there are others)

Of course, none of these address the question as asked. Still, one or the other might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(RIGHT(B1:B6,LEN(A1))=A1&""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this is excellent.  I did a few more tests on wildcards and numbers only to find it did work on a number field.  As per below it matched * on number and text

| Type | RANGE | =COUNTIF(Q4:Q6,"*"&"6") |
| --- | --- | --- |
| General | 123456 | 2 |
| Number | 123456 |  |
| Text | 123456 |  |

=SUMPRODUCT(--(RIGHT($A$2:$A$5,LEN(A1))=A1&""))
was what I used in the end so thankyou